# How to check control Type in Switch Case

Tags: c#, winforms

How to check control types in switch case statement?

```
Private void CheckControl(Control ctl) 
{
    switch (ctl) {
        case TextBox: MessageBox.Show("This is My TextBox");
        break;

        case Label: MessageBox.Show("This is My Label");
        break;
    }
}
```

Following is error in above statement:

> 'Textbox' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: using typeof(TextBox) and typeof(ctl) ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of C# 7 you can use [type patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) for this:

```
private void CheckControl(Control ctl)
{
    switch (ctl)
    {
        case TextBox _: 
            MessageBox.Show("This is My TextBox");
            break;
        case Label _: 
            MessageBox.Show("This is My Label");
            break;
    }
}
```

Here `_` is the syntax for a *discard*, meaning you don't need to access the value as a `TextBox` (or `Label`) afterwards.

If you *do* want to access members of the specific type, you can introduce a pattern variable:

```
private void CheckControl(Control ctl)
{
    switch (ctl)
    {
        case TextBox textBox: 
            // Use textBox for any TextBox-specific members here
            MessageBox.Show("This is My TextBox");
            break;
        case Label label: 
            // Use label for any Label-specific members here
            MessageBox.Show("This is My Label");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
switch (ctl?.GetType().Name) {
    case "TextBox": MessageBox.Show("This is My TextBox");
    break;

    case "Label": MessageBox.Show("This is My Label");
    break;
}
```